# How to define Macro as variable or array?

Tags: c++, macros, arduino-esp32

```
/*
    Based on Neil Kolban example for IDF: https://github.com/nkolban/esp32-snippets/blob/master/cpp_utils/tests/BLE%20Tests/SampleServer.cpp
    Ported to Arduino ESP32 by Evandro Copercini
    updates by chegewara
*/

#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>

// See the following for generating UUIDs:
// https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

#define SERVICE_UUID  "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting BLE work!");

  BLEDevice::init("Long name works now");
  BLEServer  *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                         CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                                       );

  pCharacteristic->setValue("Hello World says Neil");
  pService->start();
  // BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();  // this still is working for backward compatibility
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(true);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x06);  // functions that help with iPhone connections issue
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x12);
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
  Serial.println("Characteristic defined! Now you can read it in your phone!");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(2000);
}
```

**#define SERVICE_UUID  "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"**

**#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"**

I wanted to add more ServiceUUID and CharacteristicsUUID, to these Macro lists. How can I add to this Macro list and use it as an array?

Comment: "...to these Macro lists"  What macro lists? What's a macro list? Do you want an array of strings or what?

Comment: Why do you have to use macros? Why not just use an array if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an array of UUIDs

```
const char* SERVICE_UUID[] = {
  "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b",
  "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c3319999",
  "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c3319aaa",
  "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c3319bbb",
  "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c3319ccc"
};
```

No macros necessary

Answer (score 0):

Since c++17, you can use a constexpr [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to define your array at compile time.